# Why do they exit the While loop in the code below?

Tags: php

I don't understand why they exit the while loop in the code below. I have tried to check on google but the answer was not given.

The PHP tag was closed before

```
<h1 class="page-header">
```

and this was

```
<?php }  ?>
```

added at the end of the code to close the loop. Can someone please explain to me so I can have a better understanding of the code. Thanks.

```
           <?php 
            $query = "SELECT * FROM post";
            $select_all_post_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($select_all_post_query)){
            $post_title = $row['post_title'];
            $post_author = $row['post_author'];
            $post_date = $row['post_date'];
            $post_image = $row['post_image'];
            $post_content = $row['post_content'];

                 ?>

            <h1 class="page-header">
                Page Heading
                <small>Secondary Text</small>
            </h1>

            <!-- First Blog Post -->
            <h2>
                <a href="#"><?php echo $post_title ?></a>
            </h2>
            <p class="lead">
                by <a href="index.php"><?php echo $post_author ?></a>
            </p>
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> <?php echo $post_date ?></p>
            <hr>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/900x300" alt="">
            <hr>
            <p><?php echo $post_content ?></p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Read More <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>

            <hr>
<?php }     
                ?>
```

Comment: I am totally failing to understand what you are trying to ask

Comment: First you need to tell us where should the while loop ends if not there? They end it at last because they want to print the data coming from database in that way. It's iterating all over the required data and printing at.

Comment: you can find more information about it here http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php

Comment: @SaadSuri I understand they should end it where the code end but why was the PHP exited between the code and at the end of the loop the bracket }  have another PHP opening and closing tag to it.

Comment: The return of mysqli_fetch_assoc is NULL if there are no more rows in resultset.  That will cause the while expression to evaluate to false, that's when the exit occurs in your while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A key point of PHP is, that you can *mix it up* with HTML to generate server-side *dynamically* HTML.

The first PHP-Block is just some *ceremonial* code, that introduces some variables in a while loop, which will be echoed out later on amidst the HTML as one can see here:

```
    <!-- First Blog Post -->
    <h2>
        <a href="#"><?php echo $post_title ?></a>
    </h2>
```

*They* keep the `while loop` open since *they* want to render one blog post per iteration of the `while loop`.

Everything between:

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($select_all_post_query)){
    $post_title = $row['post_title'];
    $post_author = $row['post_author'];
    $post_date = $row['post_date'];
    $post_image = $row['post_image'];
    $post_content = $row['post_content'];

         ?>
```

And the closing:

```
<?php }     
                ?>
```

which is essentially this:

```
    <h1 class="page-header">
        Page Heading
        <small>Secondary Text</small>
    </h1>

    <!-- First Blog Post -->
    <h2>
        <a href="#"><?php echo $post_title ?></a>
    </h2>
    <p class="lead">
        by <a href="index.php"><?php echo $post_author ?></a>
    </p>
    <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> <?php echo $post_date ?></p>
    <hr>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/900x300" alt="">
    <hr>
    <p><?php echo $post_content ?></p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Read More <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>

    <hr>
```

will get echoed out as HTML **once per iteration of the while loop**. This leads to there being multiple blog posts on one HTML page.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML between the two PHP tags is part of the loop. As the loop iterates, that HTML should be emitted to the page multiple times (assuming there are multiple results returned by the query).